# How do I specify "not in" in this lambda expression?

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql, lambda

I have a quick question becuase my brain won't work with me...
Where do I specify that I want the user_id's in 'Users' that are NOT in 'Groups' ?

```
db.Users.Join(db.Groups, a => a.user_id, b => b.user_id, (a, b) => new SelectListItem
{
  Value = a.user_id.ToString(),
  Text = a.surname + " " + a.lastname
});
```

Comment: What does the database structure look like? (or is there a generated Groups property in Users?)

Comment: Each Group must have a User, but I want the Users that are not in the Group table.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The following should work (assuming that I understood your question correctly):

```
db.Users
.Where(x => !db.Groups.Any(y => y.user_id == x.user_id))
.Select(a => new SelectListItem
    {
        Value = a.user_id.ToString(),
        Text = a.surname + " " + a.lastname
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this:

```
var query =  from u in db.Users
             where !(from g in dc.Groups
                     select g.user_id)
                     .Contains(u.user_id)
             select new SelectListItem { 
                         Value = u.user_id.ToString(),
                     Text = u.surname + " " + u.lastname
         };
```

Take a look here: http://introducinglinq.com/blogs/marcorusso/archive/2008/01/14/the-not-in-clause-in-linq-to-sql.aspx

Comment: Thanks, I'm sure this would work but I needed it in lambda =)